# The inflection points of $f(x)=(x^2-4x+1)e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I got the function $f(x)=(x^2-4x+1)e^{-x}$. The task is to find the inflection points. The correct answer is $x=4-\sqrt{5}$ and $ x=4+\sqrt{5} $. I got the second derivative to $f(x)$.

But when I equal it to zero I got $x=2+\sqrt{5}$ and $ x=2 - \sqrt{5} $.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=(x^2-4x+1)e^x$?

Comment: yes exactly. sorry forgot e^x

Comment: Please check that my edits are correct.

Comment: Yes it´s correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** The answer below was written when the question asked about $f(x)=(x^2-4x+1)e^x$.

---

Consider the function $g(x)=(x^2-4x+1)e^{-x}$, a little minus sign away from $f(x)$.

The first derivative is $(-x^2+6x-5)e^{-x}$, so the stationary points are at $x=1$ and $x=5$.

The second derivative is $(x^2-8x+11)e^{-x}$. Thus the inflection points of $g(x)$ are at $x=4\pm\sqrt{5}$.

This may account for the reported book answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! this really helped. Saw I had put e^x instead of e^-x

Comment: You are welcome. The answers given to you were all dealt accurately with the question as given. I decided to reverse engineer, and find a plausible scenario that made the reported inflection points correct.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\eqalign{
  f(x)&=(x^2-4x+1)e^x\cr
  f'(x)&=(x^2-2x-3)e^x\cr
  f''(x)&=(x^2-5)e^x\ .\cr}$$
There are

- zeros at $f(x)=0$, that is, $x=2\pm\sqrt3$;
- stationary points at $f'(x)=0$, that is, $x=-1,3$;
- inflection points at $f''(x)=0$, that is, $x=\pm\sqrt5$.

I can't explain where the answer of $x=4\pm\sqrt5$ came from, are you sure you copied the question correctly?

**Edit**.  As we can now see, $f(x)=(x^2-4x+1)e^x$ as originally posed in the question was not the function that the OP intended.

Comment: the inflection points should be: x=4+sqrt(5) and x=4-sqrt(5)

Comment: No they should not, not if you have the correct $f(x)$.  That is my point.

Comment: I´m sure I´m right cause I got the answer book. But I can see you got wrong stationary points. They should be x=1 and x=5

Comment: @Kåba probably your answer book is wrong or you made a typo when writing the function equation.

Comment: You can cleary see that $x=1,5$ are not solutions of $x^2 - 2 x - 3 = 0$.

Comment: When you derivative of the (x^2-4x+1)e^x is (6x-x^2-5)e^x. Hence the stationary points are x=1 and x=5

Comment: The derivative*

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$f(x) = P(x) e^x,$$

so $f'' = P'' e^x + 2 P' e^x + e^x P = e^x (2 + 4 x - 8 + x^2- 4x +1  ) = (x^2- 5) e^x$. Since $e^x > 0 $ for  $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$, the solution of $f''(x) = 0$ is given by $x^2 -5 =0 $, so the inflection points are $x_i = \pm \sqrt{5}$.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Edit: have a look of the graph of $f(x)$ [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%28x%5E2%20-%204%20x%20%2B%201%29%20*%20exp%28x%29%2C%7Bx%2C-4-Sqrt%5B5%5D%2C4%2BSqrt%5B5%5D%7D%5D).

Comment: the inflection points should be: x=4+sqrt(5) and x=4-sqrt(5)

Comment: There must be a typo in your textbook, as @David points out in his answer. Otherwise you didn't write down the correct $f(x)$. Have a look to the link I have posted in my answer.